# Trying to resize a dynamic array and getting a bunch of errors

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I basically need to create a class for a dynamic array of ints in C++ that has the following method: add, get, resize, and size. This is what I have so far, but I am stuck at the resize method, and I am getting a bunch of errors and such. Anything I am missing? Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

```
//header file
#pragma once
#ifndef IntVector_h
#define IntVector_h
using namespace std;

class IntVector {
private:
    int* intPtr;
    int vectSize;
    int totElements;
public:
    IntVector();
    void add(int);
    int get(int);
    void resize();
    int size();
};

#endif
```

```
//implementation
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

IntVector::IntVector() {
    vectSize = 1;
    totElements = 0;
    intPtr = new int[vectSize];
}

void IntVector::add(int num) {
    if (vectSize == totElements) {
        resize();
        intPtr[totElements] = num;
        totElements++;
    }
    else {
        intPtr[totElements] = num;
        totElements++;
    }
}

int IntVector::get(int index) {
    return intPtr[index];
}

void IntVector::resize() {
    vectSize *= 2;
    int* newArr = new int[vectSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < (vectSize / 2); i++) {
        newArr[i] = intPtr[i];
    }
    delete[] intPtr;
    intPtr = newArr;
    delete[] newArr;
}

int IntVector::size() {
    return totElements;
}
```

Comment: *I am getting a bunch of errors* Which errors? Post them in the question.

Comment: Please post the exact errors (and such).

Comment: Your `resize` function deletes the newly allocated array. I don't think that's what you want to do.

Comment: Is this for learning how to implement `std::vector<int>`? if not, just use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: `int main() { IntVector i1; IntVector i2 = i1; }` -- That simple program has a double-free error if you implemented the destructor to call `delete [] intPtr`.  Go to the **Managing resources** at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to see why your code fails.  You will see that the example at the link has the same issues your code has.

Comment: `resize()` deletes both the old and new dynamically allocated array.   So, after it is done, the object contains a dangling pointer.  To fix, remove the statement `delete [] newArr`.

Comment: Also worth learning how member initialization lists in constructors work.

Comment: For a datastructures class this kind of excercise does make sense (it teaches you manual memory managment is a paint). So even if you have to write your own dynamic array, in C++ the use of new/delete is still not recommended. So you could use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` as member pointer, then resize becomes : `std::make_unique<int[]>(size);`.

Comment: However I also think your teacher should be aware of this : [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). And make sure to mention `std::vector` after the assignment is done. He has to tell something like "Now you've build your own dynamic array and know how it works, never implement something like this again and use `std::vector`".  Can you relay this message to your teacher?

Answer (score 2):

The statements

```
int* newArr = new int[vectSize];
// ...
intPtr = newArr;
delete[] newArr;
```

are wrong.

With the assignment `intPtr = newArr` you only copy the *pointer*, not the memory it points to. So after that assignment you have two pointer variables, pointing to the same memory.

When you then `delete[] newArr` you make both pointers invalid.

Solution: Don't delete the new array.

---

On another note, you really need to learn about [the rules of three and five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Without following them, `IntVector` objects can't be copied (i.e. you can't pass or return such objects by value).